# Как изменить внутренние отступы в OutlinedTextField? (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Получилось что-то вроде этого:

[image: пример OutlinedTextField]

Можно ли как-нибудь убрать отступы, из-за которых не виден текст?

Код формы:

```
OutlinedTextField(
                value = enterS,
                onValueChange = {},
                readOnly = true,
                placeholder = { Text(text = "Test")},
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(70.dp)
                    .height(40.dp),
                textStyle = TextStyle(textAlign = TextAlign.Center))
```

Comment: А что на картинке?

Comment: OutlinedTextField, код которого ниже

Comment: compose реализует material design и все отступы там жестко закодированы. так что только делать свою реализацию начиная с BasicTextField (ну или попробовать выдрать всю реализацию OutlinedTextField ради изменения одного значения)